# variable in nth child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables

Hi Im having trouble using a variable inside my nth child Jquery code. I've tried it many times and it hasn't worked. The number 1 works but var ab ac and position do not. I've tried various forms of `('+position+')`, `(' + position + ')`, `('+(position)+')`. But, none have worked...

```
var nextB = $('.nextButton');
$(nextB).click(function(){
    var AA = 1;
    var AB = 2;
    var AC = 3;
    var position = 4;
    $('#tHacks tr:nth-child(1)').hide();
    $('#tHacks tr:nth-child(AB)').hide();
    $('#tHacks tr:nth-child(AC)').hide();
    $('#tHacks tr:nth-child('+position+')').hide();
});
```

Comment: What's the HTML look like? Checked the console for errors?

Comment: Don't use `$(nextB)`, you already got element with `$('.nextButton')`, so your code looks like `$($('.nextButton'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @j08691 mentioned in a comment, you should check the console for errors. It's likely that the AB line fails and stops execution of the function. It looks like the position line is correct, so just do the AB and AC the same way.

**UPDATE:** @monkeyinsight noted an unrelated problem...cleaning that up in my example code. In addition @Kay pointed out that you are likely wanting to use AA instead of 1 from the original, so I'm adding that to the solution as well.

```
$('.nextButton').click(function(){
    var AA = 1;
    var AB = 2;
    var AC = 3;
    var position = 4;
    $('#tHacks tr:nth-child('+AA+')').hide();
    $('#tHacks tr:nth-child('+AB+')').hide();
    $('#tHacks tr:nth-child('+AC+')').hide();
    $('#tHacks tr:nth-child('+position+')').hide();
});
```

Comment: Yep, and probably the `(1)` should have been `('+AA+')`, too.

Comment: @Kay, it does look like that's his goal. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: using .eq() like: $('#tHacks tr').eq(AA).hide(); might be even nicer. .eq() does start index at 0 but if you're looking to target elements by their index in a set, you should go for it. no need to concatenate strings into jquery selectors.

Comment: I went a different route that achieved the result i wanted. I think the server i use just couldn't recognize for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your code

```
$('#tHacks tr:nth-child('+position+')').hide();
```

to

```
$('#tHacks tr:nth-child(4)').hide();
```

You can run this code in the console window of the browser to see if it works or not.

It could happen that the integer is adding to the string creating a problem in your code. Or it could happen that the nth child referring in your code doesn't exist.